# Creating dictionaries 'on-the-fly' in Swift with custom enums as the values

Tags: ios, swift, enums, nsdictionary

I'm using the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method and I'd like to pass several arguments through the `sender` parameter. In Objective-C, I was creating a NSDictionary *on-the-fly* using `@{"myKey": myValue}` syntax.

I tried several ways in Swift but the compiler always gives me an error of that kind: *'AnyObject?' does not have a member named {'Element' or 'Key'}*

How to reproduce the expected behaviour in Swift? Thanks!

EDIT: Here's my code:

```
self.stopCamera()
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backCameraVCtoFrontCameraVC", sender: [("image", image),  ("fitler", filter)])
})
```

Comment: Swift Dictionary is not an object, it is a struct.

Comment: I do agree but what's your advice to perform my operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is creating an array of tuples:

```
[("image", image),  ("fitler", filter)]
```

You need:

```
["image": image, "filter": filter]
```

As stated in the comments, `filter` is a custom enum `WDFilterType`.  You can't put that in the `NSDictionary` because `WDFilterType` isn't an `AnyObject`.  The solution is to put the `rawValue` in the dictionary and reconstitute it on the other end.

```
["image": image, "filter": filter.rawValue]
```

Then on the receiving end:

```
if let dict = sender as? NSDictionary {
    let filter = WDFilterType(rawValue: (dict["filter"] as Int))
}
```

In this case filter will be an optional (`WDFilterType?`) that must be unwrapped.

Comment: I tried this way and I got the error: *'AnyObject!' does not have a member named 'Key'*. `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backCameraVCtoFrontCameraVC", sender: ["image": image, "filter": filter])`

Comment: @sweepy_ Probably because you aren't casting it properly at the receiving end. sender is an id, which is AnyObject in Swift, you need to cast it to a dictionary before trying to get values for keys.

Comment: @Abizern The error is raised before compiling on the line mentioned above, not at the receiving end.

Comment: Are `image` and `filter` optionals?  If so, unwrap them when you create the dictionary.

Comment: Unfortunately they're not, the problem is not here.. image is of type UIImage and filter is a custom Enum.

Comment: That's your problem.  You can't put the enum in the dictionary because it isn't an `AnyObject`.  You could do `["image": image, "filter": filter.rawValue]` and then reconstitute it on the other end.

Comment: That's it, thank you so much! If anyone else get stuck on this problem, the receiver must use the value like this: `WDFilterType(rawValue: (dictionary["filter"] as Int))`